# Counting the number of values that fall in a set of between x,y,z coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am trying to write a method that allows me to count the number of objects in 3 dimensions that fall in another object with 3 dimensional coordinates. You could say this object that has values in it has a radius too, so i'm trying to count the number of object inside of a sphere.

I won't post my current script, but I'll try out with an example: I have a galaxy with 3D coordinates `gal_pos` with a radius `gal_rad`.

```
import numpy as np
gal_pos = np.array(
  [[ 528.1373291 ,  432.18615723,  443.8348999 ],
   [ 540.12231445,  450.08154297,  442.07891846],
   [ 590.73675537,  234.6769104 ,  296.02798462],
   [ 529.98809814,  161.75544739,  567.58203125],
   [ 552.45446777,  312.1973877 ,  375.42492676],
   [ 700.94335938,   65.46828461,  172.71842957],
   [ 463.43258667,   73.57706451,  285.4147644 ],
   [ 547.74414062,  330.9855957 ,  401.49771118],
   [ 591.89801025,  196.19670105,  274.60073853],
   [ 581.28320312,  376.70013428,  359.81851196],
   [ 520.09820557,  302.17849731,  371.68771362],
   [ 812.84539795,   97.41672516,  150.87428284],
   [ 541.6552124 ,   17.40070724,  373.07562256],
   [ 523.34509277,  302.18151855,  503.6333313 ]])

gal_rad = np.array(
  [ 1.14752779,  1.02471195,  0.79648002,  0.6085083 ,  0.78725676,
    1.07809084,  0.57744866,  0.93733404,  0.76053329,  0.68979678,
    0.61188519,  1.07989271,  0.83872035,  0.59899661])
```

I then also have stars with 3D positions `star_pos`.

```
star_pos = np.array(
  [[ 517.0300293 ,  264.54165649,  547.87835693],
   [ 530.37280273,  358.40835571,  455.68734741],
   [ 530.42211914,  358.20803833,  455.80908203],
   [ 530.86737061,  324.91717529,  407.96405029],
   [ 547.05175781,  333.9262085 ,  403.82403564],
   [ 530.61053467,  325.91259766,  407.04153442],
   [ 533.9979248 ,  331.18804932,  451.3795166 ],
   [ 531.20678711,  326.75308228,  406.44711304],
   [ 550.81237793,  340.88101196,  408.75830078],
   [ 519.52880859,  299.91259766,  516.25140381],
   [ 525.82739258,  301.46209717,  501.66738892],
   [ 524.87988281,  268.88357544,  510.0123291 ],
   [ 524.43371582,  299.99725342,  512.36077881],
   [ 524.40429688,  299.8979187 ,  512.57452393],
   [ 524.40765381,  299.89120483,  512.5032959 ],
   [ 545.57440186,  331.59066772,  401.20291138],
   [ 532.29016113,  306.27557373,  491.26434326],
   [ 530.77410889,  326.18057251,  407.06216431],
   [ 524.14819336,  306.60586548,  509.55993652]])
```

Above are only just a sample of the values I have.

```
xmax_rad = gal_pos[:,0]+gal_rad
xmin_rad = gal_pos[:,0]-gal_rad

ymax_rad = gal_pos[:,1]+gal_rad
ymin_rad = gal_pos[:,1]-gal_rad

zmax_rad = gal_pos[:,2]+gal_rad
zmin_rad = gal_pos[:,2]-gal_rad

tot_pop = [] # Total population found each galaxy

Nind = [(x,y,z) for x,y,z in enumerate(star_pos) 
        if any(xmin_rad <=x<= xmax_rad) and 
        any(ymin_rad<=y<=ymax_rad) 
        and any(zmin_rad<=x<=zmax_rad)]
tot_pop.append(Nind)

print tot_pop
```

This method I am trying out makes the most sense to me by breaking down everything, but this is being used for arrays of sizes ~300, but is returns  `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack` for `Nind`. Likely due to the fact my the iteration cannot unpack 3 objects?

I have tried other methods where I take that magnitude of each of the positions, but it returns incorrect results, as well counting the values via histogram, but again, returns incorrect results (I check by projecting everything in a 2d histogram). This method where i index for each galaxy returns null arrays for each galaxy:

```
tot_pop = []
for k in np.arange(len(gal_pos)):
    Nind = [(x,y) for x,y in enumerate(star_pos) 
        if xmin_rad[k] <=x<= xmax_rad[k]) and 
        ymin_rad[k]<=y<=ymax_rad[k]]

    tot_pop.append(Nind)
```

Comment: What are the shapes of the relevant inputs?

Comment: @MSeifert @Divakar Hi, sorry, I should have included those. The shape of `star_pos` in my analysis (128, 3) and is in fact a NumPy array. Similarly `gal_pos` is of shape (14, 3) and is also a NumPy array. I will include some values in my post momentarily!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `zip` to iterate over the galaxies + radii and then use broadcasting and boolean indexing to find matches:

```
result = []
for galaxy, galaxy_radius in zip(gal_pos, gal_rad):
    # With broadcasting you can simply subtract the positions from the galaxy center
    # and using abs avoids checking lower and upper bound.
    rel_star_pos = abs(star_pos - galaxy)
    # Check which distances are below the radius and keep these which are
    # within the radius for x, y and z
    matches = (rel_star_pos <= galaxy_radius).all(axis=1)
    # use boolean indexing to append the stars which satisfy the above condition
    result.append(star_pos[matches])
print(result)
```

In case you want to append the indices (not the actual star coordinates) you can change the `append` line to:

```
result.append(np.where(matches)[0])
```

Or if you just want the number of matches:

```
result.append(np.sum(matches))
```

However I couldn't find any matches with the given data:

```
[array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
 array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
 array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
 array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
 array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
 array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
 array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
 array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
 array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
 array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
 array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
 array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
 array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64),
 array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)]
```

Comment: While the values I gave did not give results, the other 100 values I had showed up a couple of times! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one almost vectorized approach making use of efficient [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and `slicing` to help out as well -

```
# Define low and high limits
l = gal_pos - gal_rad[:,None]
h = gal_pos + gal_rad[:,None]

# Get mask of valid ones for each row of star_pos
mask = np.ones(star_pos.shape[0], dtype=bool)
for i in range(star_pos.shape[1]):
    mask &= ((l[:,i,None] <= star_pos[:,i]) & (h[:,i,None] >= star_pos[:,i])).any(0)

# Finally use the mask to select valid rows off star_pos
out = star_pos[mask]
```

Calling it as almost vectorized, because we are still iterating through the number of columns in `star_pos`. But, since we are dealing with `X,Y,Z` data, that would be `3`. So, it's safe to call it almost vectorized for that reason.

For the given sample, here's what I get -

```
In [302]: out
Out[302]: array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)
```

So, no points from `star_pos` is satisfying the limits.

Comment: hm, interesting. I'm struggling a bit with the `any` and `|`. I don't think that's correct. I thought it should be within the "range" for all 3 coordinates.

Comment: @MSeifert I guess that `any(xmin_rad <=x<= xmax_rad)` got me confused. Fixed.

Comment: Much better now :) I tend to **not** fully-vectorized solutions (by expanding dimensions) for such problems because it's too easy to run out of memory - because you end up with 2 n*m arrays which can exhaust even computers with much RAM if the datasets are of significant size. In this case it's only about length 300 arrays so no problem here so +1 :)

Comment: @MSeifert Well this stays 2D because of the slicing. Just making use of the fact that we only XYZ (3 cols).

Comment: Yeah, but 2D arrays of size: length of array 1 (galaxies) times length of array 2 (stars). No problem here but if both arrays are thousands of elements long this will use a lot of RAM.

Comment: @MSeifert Yup that's there! As with any vectorized solution that needs a setup upfront.